# inserting value from one table to another table

Tags: c#

I have `table A (id, name)`
and `table B (condition_id, condition_name)`
and `table C (family_history_id, condition_name, id)`

can please someone help me make some query in c# in transferring `id` and `condition_name` in `table C`

Comment: i know its wrong and i dont have anymore idea on how to make a query that will run correctly

Comment: @Saragis i tried this kind of query "Insert INTO table C (condition_name, id) SELECT id, condition_name FROM table B"

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that in the first place. Restudy your design. Your table C should have the IDs from table A and Table B, not a value from table B. If the design was considered to be right, then you could do this like this (SQL way):

```
string sql = @"insert into tableC 
                (condition_name, id)
               select condition_name, @id
               from tableB where condition_id = @condition_id";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", yourPersonId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@condition_id", yourConditionId);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But again, you have a design problem.